# A method of showing how mass increases with higher velocity. I don't get it

Tags: special-relativity

I am a high schooler interested in physics and recently started reading a book about relativity. The name of the book is "What Is Relativity" by Jeffrey Bennet. In page 54 there is a paragraph that shows how velocity is related with the length and mass of an object. In the book, it says that at 0.99c, time runs at 14% as normal and the length is also 14% long as it was at rest. However the book suddenly says that the mass is 1 divided by 14%, giving 7.1. I don't understand why it suddenly divided by 0.14 when it kept saying the time and length was not divided and just stated it was 14%. Is there something about mass that I am missing here? I was confused about this and searched many answers on this website, but I couldn't find a straightforward, easy answer.

P.S. do not bother by saying mass is an invariant quantity and that it is actually the energy that is changing and that the book is wrong. My question is not whether this method is right, but why the book divided by 14% when calculating the mass change in an observer's point if view.

It is an easy question because I am feeling that I am missing something that is presumed knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: $1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2} = 0.708 $ for $\beta=0.99$. This is the dilation factor (or compression factor) for time and space under a lorentz transform (that is to say, when changing frame of reference in Special Relativity).

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that as we pass each other at high speed, we each throw a 1-pound rock at each other, and the rocks collide and stick together.

From my point of view, you rock travels only 14% as  fast as mine, so I might expect that when the rocks collide, the new combined rock will continue traveling in the direction that mine was traveling.  You, of course, will say the same thing in reverse.  We can't both be right, and in fact by the symmetry of the situation it's clear that the combined rock will stop dead.

Now how can I explain this?  How was your 14-mph rock able to stop my 100-mph rock?  There are various ways to think about it, but one natural explanation, from my point of view, is that your rock must have been heavier than mine, by just enough to compensate for the fact that it was slower.  If it was slower by a factor of 14%, it must have been heavier by a factor of 1/14%.  That is, its mass grew by 1/14% as a result of the fact that you were moving.

Now that turns out not to be the language that a lot of people prefer to use these days, because people prefer to reserve the word "mass" for something a little different.  But the author of your book apparently prefers this language, and there's nothing wrong with it as long as you keep careful track of what it means and don't confuse this use of the word "mass" with other, more common uses.   (Though it seems clear from your "PS" that you already understand this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what you said, the book gives a statement and does not give any reason, so there is no reason for us to respond to!

However, I can create one. Imagine a photon. This has a wavelength of $\lambda$, and an energy $E=hc/\lambda$. This the statement that short wavelength light is of high energy (eg, blue or ultraviolet), and long wavelength light is of low energy (eg, red, infrared, radio). If, in your new frame of reference, $\lambda'=\lambda/\gamma$, meaning the wavelength is contracted by a factor $\gamma>1$ (in our case, $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.99^2}}=1/0.14$), then the energy in this new frame is $E'=h c/\lambda'=h c \gamma/\lambda=\gamma E$. The energy is multiplied by a factor of $\gamma$.

So, in the sense of mass-energy equivalence, the mass increases by a factor of $\gamma$. (Mass-energy equivalence is the only sense in which "the mass increases". Modern physicists prefer to say that the energy is $\gamma m c^2$, where $m$ is the invariant rest mass. Old physicists would say the energy is just $m' c^2$, where $m'$ is the "relativistic mass" equal to $m\gamma$, $\gamma$ times the rest mass. But this is confusing and not very intellectually pleasing in my opinion.)

There is probably some nice Einstein gedankenexperiment where this makes it obvious that the same must hold true for all massive objects (ie, not just light), but it escapes me right now.